# is the "solver" feature in google spreadsheets accessible via google-apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use access the google spreadsheet's solver feature from google-apps-script.  Does anyone know whether this feature is included in the current release of app-script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's currently supported in Apps Script, but if you'd like, you can submit a feature request via the issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

edit: it's issue number 1348 ([link](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1348)).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea exposing an Solver done in a spreadsheet via a script allows an easier way to make changes without adjusting code....

Comment: Yes, the solver in google-apps-spreadsheet doesn't remember any of your previous selections from one run to the next, so you have to reset your objective and constraints everytime you run the solver.